# What java version do I actually have installed on my Mac?

Tags: java, variables, installation, java-home

When I go to the terminal and type in

`echo $JAVA_HOME`

I get `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64`

My understanding as per oracle site, is that 1.8.0 means I have java 8:

"In JDK 8 and JRE 8, the version strings are 1.8 and 1.8.0."
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk8-naming.html

But when I type in the terminal
`java -version`
I get
`openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19`

Do I leave it as it is? or should I go ahead and make the info match.

I actually need version 8 for work purposes.

A little more of info:
See the thing is I initially downloaded JAVA version 17.0.1 from oracle's official site, installed it and everything. Then I downloaded Jetbrains IntelliJ IDE, and once it was installed, it suggested that JDK was missing or something like that, and that IntelliJ would take care of it with no hassle. The IDE worked just fine, projects ran beautifully, and I didn't pay that much attention to the issue above explained (Didn't even noticed it).

Thank you for your insights.

---

Edit Jun8.

So well guys it seems the echo $JAVA_HOME was throwing an erroneous path, for reasons that I don't know, see I got the proof here [image]

And now after doing nothing, It is showing a path that makes more sense.

[image]

It seems "JAVA_HOME" path got fixed to JAVA 17 by itself.

Comment: What path does `which java` give you? It looks like you have installed two JVM instances and some paths are pointing to different ones. This is likely going to lead to headaches down the road.

Comment: Put this line in one of your programs:`System.out.println ("Using Java version " + System.getProperty("java.version"));` See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: I suggest you delete any and all JVMs you installed manually. You should them in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`.  Then let IntelliJ mange downloading JVMs for you. Or else, use SDKMAN.

Comment: FYI, Oracle is only one of about a dozen vendors providing JDKs: Azul Systems, BellSoft, Amazon, Red Hat, IBM, SAP, Pivotal, Oracle, Microsoft, Adoptium, etc. Most of their products are based on the same codebase from the *OpenJDK* project. Choose the vendor that matches your technical, support, and licensing needs. See [*Java Is Still Free*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-3-0-0-ocrt-2021-bca75c88d23b).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Silvio: Which java throws "/usr/bin/java". @James: The sysout prints "Using Java version 17.0.1"

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Which java throws "/usr/bin/java"

Comment: @BasilBourque I looked at the "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/" and it was empty. But then I went to my user's  "/Users/new/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines" and found `openjdk-17.0.1openjdk-17.0.1`

Comment: Hey guys, I don't what happened, but when I do `echo $JAVA_HOME` I now get `new@news-MacBook-Pro / % echo $JAVA_HOME
/Users/new/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.0.1/Contents/Home` ... I don't know where was mac getting the `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64` from. When I look for that directory(the 1.8.0) it doesn't even exist. Interesting magic going on here. Well it is for sure 17.0.1 all the way. So I gotta go into changing that back 8. Thanks a lot for your support.